# Define Mail Subject Using NSSharingService

Tags: macos, cocoa, email, osx-mountain-lion, sharing

How do you define the subject for a Mail message composed with NSSharingService?

I've been through the [NSSharingService Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012270), but am not seeing it defined anywhere. The following successfully launches mail app, but subject is just shoved into the mail body along with the text.

```
NSAttributedString *text = [self.noteSynopsisView attributedString];
NSString *subject = @"My Subject";
NSArray *shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:text, subject, nil];
NSSharingServicePicker *sharingServicePicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:shareItems];
sharingServicePicker.delegate = self;
[sharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect:[self.shareButton bounds] ofView:self.shareButton preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
```

In iOS, you'd normally do something like the following to define a subject for the MailComposer

```
[sharingServicePicker setSubject:@"My Subject"];
```

But SharingServicePicker does not support setSubject.

Answer (score 2):

As of OS X 10.9, `NSSharingService` has a [`subject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSSharingService/subject) property which you can use.

Comment: if ([mailShare respondsToSelector:@selector(setSubject:)] [mailShare setSubject:@"Subject"];

Answer (score 0):

Implement the next method:

```
-(id<NSSharingServiceDelegate>)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingServicePicker delegateForSharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService{
    sharingService.subject=@"Subject";
    return self;
}
```